# Removing duplicate files with same size in shell script

Tags: shell, duplicates

I have a directory which has the multiple files with same content but different names, the only criteria I thought of to remove the duplicates was to sort them based on size and then remove the ones having same size, for instance when I type

```
 find . -type f -printf "%p - %s\n" | uniq -D -f1 | sort -nr -k3
```

I get

> ```
>    ./abc.txt - 595
>    ./acd.txt - 595
>    ./dbc.txt - 595
>    ./jed.txt - 595
>    ./end.txt - 595
>    ./wtw.txt - 595
>    ./hds.txt - 595
>    ./dkd.txt - 523
>    ./kjk.txt - 523
> ```

I would like to keep only

> ```
>    ./abc.txt 
>    ./dkd.txt
> ```

Comment: Same size is not a real guarantee of being the same file. If you want to compare file contents use a sum of the file (md5, sha1, sha256, etc.) and compare those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> find . -type f -printf "%p - %s\n" | uniq -D -f1 | sort -nr -k3
> ```

- `uniq` needs the input sorted, so you'd have to put `sort` before it.
- The `uniq` option `-D` is out of place here.
- The `sort` option `-u` can do the job of `uniq`.

---

```
find . -type f -printf "%p - %s\n" | sort -nru -k3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that you can copy out one version of the duplicates:

```
find . -type f -printf "%p - %s\n" | uniq -d -f1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -I{} cp {} /path/to/dir
```